# Identifying easy subsets/instances of NP-hard problems?

Tags: np-complete

Say I want to solve a set of problems. I know that I can map my problem as a problem that is known to be hard in the general case (say, inference in Bayesian networks). But my set only contains instances which will map to easy instances - (say, having a tree-structure when cast to a BN inference problem)

I know BNs with tree-structures have linear-time inference algorithms. If I didn't, I may have given up on exact solutions in favour of loose approximations.

(2nd, looser example: I find myself needing to solve SAT, but turns out I can easily reduce all my problem instances to 2-SAT)

Is there a common approach to determine whether a given subset of a hard problem is hard or not? How does one typically approach this? Are these well studied

Comment: Does "look it up in Garey/Johnson, which often lists more tractable special cases" count as "an approach"? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad topic.  Every problem is a special case of some hard problem.  For instance, most problems (both hard and easy ones) can be viewed as a special case of the halting problem, but that doesn't really help us distinguish hard from easy problems.  It all depends on the details.  I don't think there's any general answer at this level of abstraction.